# How to change the href of a button?

Tags: html, button, input, href

I have a this:

```
<input type="submit" class="inputlogin submit" name="register" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="Maak mijn account en log in!">
```

and then it goes to register/register. I want that it goes to /me, how I can do this?

Comment: Change the value for action in the form to /me ( i am assuming you have coded the form)

Comment: @KunjanThadani Where I can find the value for action?

Comment: <form action="/me" method="post">

Comment: Show sufficient code for reproducing the issue, and explain what the issue is. “Goes to register” does not really say what happens. Minimally, you need to include a `form` element and explain what happens when it is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Musa, welcome to stack overflow!

The submit button does exactly what its name says: It submits a form. Now **where** the form is submitted to is not a property of the submit button, but of the form.

You will find, that the submit button is part of a `<form action="..."> .. </form>` construct. By changing the *action* property of the form, you can point it to another URL, e.g. to ' /me'

Answer (score 0):

The page the input refers to is defined in the action attribute of the `<form>` not the `<input>` itself.

```
<form action="/me" method="get">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like this:

```
<form action="/me" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="inputlogin submit" name="register" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="Maak mijn account en log in!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused right now. So, I have `<input type="submit" class="inputlogin submit" name="register" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="Maak mijn account en log in!">` and that I need to change to: `<input action="/me" method="get" type="submit" class="inputlogin submit" name="register" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="Maak mijn account en log in!">` maybe I needed this to say earlier, but it's a registration form, so it needs to be checked if everything is filled in, and it needs to get in the database.

Comment: No. you are mixing form and input tags. Please check my answer for writing a form. Better have a look at basics of html.

Comment: This is not an answer. To clarify what you are asking, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be this:

```
<input type="button" class="inputlogin submit" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="Maak mijn account en log in!" onclick="parent.location='/me'">
```

This makes use of onclick and will work without a form. Remember that it doesn't `POST` a form

Answer (score 0):

So, I see now that I already had the right code, but it goes to /register/me.. I'm really ashamed...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text" style="font-weight:bold;padding:10px;"><?php if(isset($template->form->error)) { echo '<div class="error-messages-holder"><ul><li><p class="error-message">'.$template->form->error.'</p></li></ul></div>'; } ?>
        <form method="post" action="{url}/me" autocomplete="off">
          <label for="index_rusername">Neem een unieke nickname:</label><br />
          <input type="text" placeholder=" Jouw gebruikersnaam " class="inputlogin" name="reg_username"><br />
          <label for="index_rpassword">Kies een sterk wachtwoord:</label><br />
          <input type="password" placeholder=" Jouw wachtwoord " class="inputlogin" name="reg_password"><br />
          <label for="index_rconpassword">Typ je wachtwoord over:</label><br />
          <input type="password" placeholder=" Jouw wachtwoord " class="inputlogin"  name="reg_rep_password"><br />
          <label for="index_remail">Jouw email adres:</label><br />
          <input type="text" placeholder=" Jouw e-mail adres " class="inputlogin"  name="reg_email"><br />
          <input type="submit" class="inputlogin submit" name="register" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="Maak mijn account en log in!">
        </form>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I have this code now. But if I press on the button, it doesn't register in the database, so all the configurated things doesn't come in in the table "users".